# android studio store speed and calculate distance

Tags: android

i have a requestLocationUpdates=> in every 5s, the location will be updated. And i wanna calculate the distance in every 5s and then store it into an array. Also, i wanna store the location.getSpeed into an array too, so that i can use the speed saved in array to draw a graph in the next interface.
here are my codes:

```
 private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
    String where = "";
    if (location != null) {

        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        double lat = location.getLatitude();

        float speed = location.getSpeed();

        long time = location.getTime();
        String timeString = getTimeString(time);

        where = "Lng: " + lng +
                "\nLat: " + lat +
                "\nSpeed: " + speed +
                "\nTime: " + timeString +
                "\nProvider: " + "gps";


        showMarkerMe(lat, lng);
        cameraFocusOnMe(lat, lng);
        trackToMe(lat, lng);

    }else{
        where = "No location found.";
    }


    txt.setText(where);
}
```

Comment: So.. what is your problem? Calculating the distance, saving data/enter data into a array/arraylist?

Comment: if i use distanceBetween, it requires two locations, but i can only get one each time, i dunno how to store the previous one. Also, i am new to android, i dunno to write in this code to make an array and store the speed. I know distanceBetween is stored in array list. but i dunno how to do this in this method, as this method will be run in every 5s, dunno if data will be overlapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About [storing data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) you have different options. You could use a `database`, where you oput your data, read it and be able to read it again the next time you use your app. If you want the data only to be persistent in the current app lifecycle, I recommend using an `ArrayList` of custom Objects. Short example of `ArrayList<LocationObject>` usage:

```
public class LocationObject {
    private double lng;
    private double lat;
    private float speed;
    private long time;

    public LocationObject(long time, double lng, double lat, float speed) {
        this.time = time;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    //put getters  & setters here, press `Alt` and `Insert`, choose the getters and setters

}
```

In  your running `Activity`, initialize an `ArrayList` globally (not inside a method, but inside your `Activity.class`:

```
private ArrayList<LocationObject> locationList;

//in onCreate:
locationList = new ArrayList<LocationObject>();

//whenever you retrieve a location, create a LocationObject and store it into the List:
LocationObject currentLocation = new LocationObject(time, lng, lat, speed);
locationList.add(currentLocation);
```

Now, if you want to get the last 2 locations, you simply access them in the list:

```
LocationObject lastLocation = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 2);
LocationObject currentLocation = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);

//to get the latitude, don't forget to create the getters&setters in your LocationObject.class!
double lastLat = lastLocation.getLat();
```

Edit: To store only the last value, just assign the values to a globally declared variable:

```
private Location oldLocation;
private float[] results;
private ArrayList<float> speedList;


//in oncreate: 
speedList = new ArrayList<Float>();


private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
String where = "";
results = new float[100]; //[100] means there can be 100 entries - decrease or increase the number depending on your output
if (location != null) {

    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    float speed = location.getSpeed();
    long time = location.getTime();
    String timeString = getTimeString(time);

    speedList.add(speed);

    if(oldLocation != null){
        Location.distanceBetween(oldLocation.getLatitude(), oldLocation.getLongitude(), lat, lng, results);
    } 
    oldLocation = location;
```

Comment: i wanna calculate the distance using distanceBetween, how to put it into my method? i mean this method can only get one location each time, saving all the locations is not my purpose, i just wanna get the previous one and the current one to calculate the dis.

Comment: Yes, the above would be a solution if you want to store more Locations than only the last one.

Comment: What do you mean? You can access the old Speed via `oldLocation.getSpeed()`.

Comment: so i mean how to create an array to store the speed too?

Comment: So, you want to store the last and the current speed or more? Why do you want an array to do this..?

Comment: your edited ans+ speed, as i will use the speed that i have saved to draw a graph

Comment: I added a list for the speed.

Comment: so i should write speedlist  = location.getSpeed(); ?

Comment: No. I added the line to add things to the list also. It's `speedList.add(location.getSpeed());`